# Как вывести все элементы arraylist с определенными именим?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

```
class Firma {

    static ArrayList<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<City> cityList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Object> saleList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Voucher> voucherList = new ArrayList<>();



    public static void AddList(Client user) {
        clientList.add(user);
    }

    public void AddList(int key_client, String name, String phone_number, String passport_id, int skidka) {
        clientList.add(new Client(key_client,name,phone_number,passport_id,skidka));
    }
}

class Client {


        public int key_client;
        public static String name;
        public String phone;
        public String passport_id;
        public int skidka;


        public Client(int key_client, String name, String phone, String passport_id, int skidka) {
            this.key_client = key_client;
            this.name = name;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.passport_id = passport_id;
            this.skidka = skidka;
        }

    

    @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User{" +
                    "key_client=" + key_client +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                    ", passport_id='" + passport_id + '\'' +
                    ", skidka=" + skidka +
                    '}';
        }
}
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", new Locale("ru"));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int key_Client = 0, id_City = 0, id_Voucher = 0, id_Sale = 0;
        boolean b = true;

        //Колонка Клиента
        do  {
            key_Client++;
            System.out.println("Введите имя клиента, номер телефона, номер паспорта и скидку разделяйте их двумя пробелами");
            String prodStr1 = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] client = prodStr1.split("  ");
            Firma.AddList(new Client(key_Client,client[0], client[1], client[2], Integer.parseInt(client[3].trim())));

            System.out.println("Введите Y или y для продолжения");
            String check = scanner.nextLine();
            if (check.contains("Y") || check.contains("y")) {
                b = true;
            } else {
                b = false;
            }
        } while (b == true);

 for (Object v_client : Firma.clientList)
    {
        System.out.println(Client.name);
    }

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне выбрать все добавленые в список елементы с именим name и вывести их, а не только последнего пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В `System.out.println(Client.name);` что есть `Client.name`?  Переменной `Client` я не нашёл, а значит это класс (т.к. он присутствует). Поле `name` не статично и к нему нельзя обратиться из класса. Как у вас этот код вообще работает...

Comment: @ArchDemon, Я забыл отредактировать name статическая

Comment: Тогда рекомендую вам ознакомиться с отличием статическими атрибутами класса и не статическими

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывести несложно, только у вас проблема с именованием переменных, все поля по какой-то публичные и класс Firma в таком виде вообще не нужен (его реализация нарушает все принципы и паттерны, включая SOLID, GRASP).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String searchName = "";
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int keyClient = 0;
        List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            System.out.println("Введите имя клиента, номер телефона, номер паспорта и скидку разделяйте их двумя пробелами");
            String[] client = scanner.nextLine().split("  ");
            clientList.add(new Client(++keyClient, client[0], client[1], client[2], Integer.parseInt(client[3].trim())));
            System.out.println("Введите Y или y для продолжения");
        } while ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase()));

        for (Client client : clientList) {
            if (searchName.equals(client.getName())) {
                System.out.println(client);
            }
        }
    }

}

class Client {

    private final int keyClient;
    private final String name;
    private final String phone;
    private final String passportId;
    private final int skidka;

    public Client(int keyClient, String name, String phone, String passportId, int skidka) {
        this.keyClient = keyClient;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.passportId = passportId;
        this.skidka = skidka;
    }

    public int getKeyClient() {
        return keyClient;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getPassportId() {
        return passportId;
    }

    public int getSkidka() {
        return skidka;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{"
                + "key_client=" + keyClient
                + ", name='" + name + '\''
                + ", phone='" + phone + '\''
                + ", passport_id='" + passportId + '\''
                + ", skidka=" + skidka
                + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну задание в колледже дали на С#,я спросил или на джаве и пытаюсь сам разобраться, вроде язіки похржие, но иногда что-то кординально разное,а эти методы(SOLID, GRASP) не изучал еще(

Comment: @MonKeyLAb_vlad, уверяю вас, если бы написали на C# было бы одинаково плохо и не работало бы